# Given $f\in Hol(|z|<1)$ and $image(f(z))\subset K\subset D_0(1)$ where K is compact subset Prove that $f$ has one fixed point.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Given $f\in Hol(|z|<1)$ and $image(f(z))\subset K\subset D_0(1)$ where K is compact subset
Prove that $f$ has one fixed point.

My try is:
$g(z)=z-f(z)$ and then we know that $|f(z)|<1$ using Rouche theorem $1=|z|>|f(z)|$ and because $z$ has only 1 zero we get the needed.
I'm not sure if my prove is correct

Comment: You cannot apply Rouche's Theorem to the unit circle since $f$ is not even defined on the circle. Besides, how do you get $|z| >|f(z)|$?

Comment: amm maybe because image of $f$ is in K and therefore it is bounded

Comment: I  mistook $im f(z)$ for the imaginary part of $f(z)$.

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply Rouche's Theorem to the  unit circle. But there exist $t\in (0,1)$ such that $|f(z)| <t$ for all $z$. For any $r \in (t,1)$ we can apply Rouche's Theorem to see that $f$ has  a unique fixed point in $\{z: |z| <r\}$ for every $r \in (t,1)$ . This implies that $f$ has  a unique fixed point in $\{z: |z|<1\}$.

Comment: thanks :) can we change that image $f$ is a subset of closed set in the disc?

Comment: oh yea right :) stupid question